# Insertar en PostgreSql un fichero Excel

Tags: postgresql, excel, angular, spring-boot

Estoy buscando información sobre como insertar un fichero excel en PostgreSql, pero no encuentro información, no hay una guía o tutorial de cero, todo son problemas concretos los que hay en internet.

Mi intención es que el cliente (Angular2) mande un excel al servidor (SpringBoot) y guarda en la Base de datos (postgreSQL), los datos del excell.

Necesito un código para empezar o algo, pero no encuentro por donde empezar.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Analizando tú pregunta puedes usar como referencia [r2dbc-postgresql](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-postgresql).

1. Conocer el concepto de Maven y la forma como accedes a los repositorios.
2. Escoge una IDE para implementar la practica.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy familiarizado con sprint-boot, pero la manera más eficiente de meter un excel en postgres, a mi gusto, es usar `ogr2ogr`, una extensión que se instala con la librería [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/).

La instalación en Ubuntu (no dices que OS usas) se hace con:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install gdal-bin
```

Con eso instalado puedes hacer:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=localhost user=postgres dbname=geoexamples" archivo.xlsx
```

O convertirlo en un SQL:

```
ogr2ogr -f PGDump archivo.xlsx
```

GDAL tiene bindings para java:

- [GDALOgr in Java](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJava)
- [ogr2ogr.java](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/java/apps/ogr2ogr.java)

aparentemente necesitas instalar ambos según [esta respuesta de Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192695/how-to-run-gdal-ogr2ogr-in-java-to-convert-shapefiles-to-geojson#answer-28429158). Con eso podrías correr `ogr2ogr` desde tu programa, pero en caso contrario siempre tienes la opción de correrlo instanciando un subproceso [cmdLine](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html).